# How can I split a string at a keyword in zshell and save the result?

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I'm new to the zshell and trying to split a string using a keyword as the delimiter. The output is from netfilter and not always at a fixed position so I need to split at the keywords I'm interested in.

I've found a way that works, but seems like there should be a much simpler way to do it. Any thoughts?

```
line="[Thu Jul 23 12:29:50 2015] IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=10.1.1.17 DST=10.101.11.1  PROTO=TCP SPT=46286 DPT=1113 SYN URGP=0 "

# this returns a substring starting from 'SRC=' to the end
tmp=${(MS)line##SRC=*}

# use the first element returned in the substring
src=$tmp[(w)1] 

echo "src is $src"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse a single keyword, I'd use a regular expression match with the `=~` [conditional operator](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html#Conditional-Expressions).

```
if [[ $line =~ [[:space:]]SRC=[^[:space:]]+ ]]; then
  echo src is $MATCH[6,$#MATCH]
else
  echo >&2 No SRC=
fi
```

To parse multiple keywords, I'd split the string minus the timestamp at whitespace using [parameter expansion constructs](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion) and store the output in an associative array.

```
timestamp=${${line%%\]*}##*\[}
typeset -A info
for x in ${=line#*\]}; do
  if [[ $x = *=* ]]; then
    info[${x%%=*}]=${x#*=}
  else
    info[$x]=
  fi
done
echo src is $info[SRC]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could almost turn `line` into an associative array, but the `key=value` items seem too irregular since sometimes the `=` is missing and sometimes there’s no `value`. So one way to go is simply splitting the whole `line` on spaces and putting it into elements of an array. It’s not clear how order dependent the output is, but if you can count on desired keys existing and being in consistent order, one approach would be:

```
ary=( ${(s. .)line} )  # split on spaces, storing into array
print $ary[8]
SRC=10.1.1.17
```

Now you can get at any key-value by index. You could also use this array as a starting point to a true associative array.

You might want to remove the datestamp stuff (`[...]`) first.